# How do i query a SQL databse with 3 different tables which contains information about actors, plays, and roles performed?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Database contains information about actors, plays, and roles performed.

```
Actor(actor_id, name, year_born) 
Play(play_id, title, author, year_written) 
Role(actor_id, character_name, play_id)
```

Why These attempts are wrong?

To DO:

1. SQL query that returns the name of the actors that were born in 1980 and have played in more than 5 plays.
   2.SQL query that returns the name of the actor(s) that played in all plays written by the author “Arthur Miller”.

My Attempt for problem 1

```
Select DISTINCT a.name
From Actor a , Role r , Play p
Where a.year_born = 1980
HAVING count(DISTINCT r.play_id) > 5
```

My Attempt for problem 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name
From Actor a , Role r , Play p
Where p.author = “Arthur Miller” AND p.play_id=r.play_id and r.actor_id = a.actor_id
HAVING count (DISTINCT a.actor_id = p.play_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

In both queries You have missed group by clause. And since you are using group by distinct keyword in select list is not needed.

Problem 1:

```
  Select a.name
    From Actor a inner join  Role r on a.actor_id=r.actor_id
    Where a.year_born = 1980
    Group by a.name
    HAVING count(DISTINCT r.play_id) > 5
```

Problem 2:

```
SELECT a.name
From Actor a inner join Role r 
on r.actor_id = a.actor_id
inner join Play p
on p.play_id=r.play_id 
Where p.author = 'Arthur Miller' 
group by a.name
HAVING count (distinct p.play_id) =(select count(*) from Play where author = 'Arthur Miller' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the table tables first,

Eg:
NOTE* As the role table contains both actor_id and play_id, I am taking the role table as the base table.

```
select a.name
from role as r
inner join actor as a On a.actor_id = r.actor_id
inner join play as p On r.play_id = p.play_id
where p.author = "Arthur Miller”
```